# Использование UNICODE и ANSI в VС++, Windows

Tags: windows, ansi, c++, unicode, visual-c++

При изучении оконного интерфейса в Windows, потребовалось использовать функцию

```
BOOL WINAPI SetDlgItemText(
_In_  HWND hDlg,
_In_  int nIDDlgItem,
_In_  LPCTSTR lpString)
```

которая помещает текст в EDIT CONTROL, через указатель LPCTSTR, столкнулся поближе с использованием кодировок (UNICODE и ANSI), как я понял где-то в макросах определено, что LPCTSTR может быть как UNICODE так и ANSI

1. Kак в моём проекте задать нужную мне кодировку?
2. Могу ли я в диалоговом окне использовать одни контролы с UNICODE, другие с ANSI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Kак в моём проекте задать нужную мне кодировку?

И [[@Аsen](/users/8168/%D0%B0sen)](/users/8168/%D0%B0sen) и [[@manking](/users/7538/manking)](/users/7538/manking) указали оба способа:

1) поставить напрямую, в коде:

UNICODE:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
```

ANSI:

```
#undef UNICODE
#undef _UNICODE
```

2) выставить в свойствах проекта (для vs): **Configuration properties -> General -> Character Set**

лично я предпочитаю второй вариант

> Могу ли я в диалоговом окне использовать одни контролы с UNICODE, другие с ANSI?

Для большинства компонент Windows существует обе реализации: и ANSI и UNICODE,
т.е. можно конечно их смешивать. Для этого нужно пользоваться соответствующими версиями:

1. **Имен** классов компонент ( RICHEDIT_CLASSA, RICHEDIT_CLASSW, WC_EDITA, WC_EDITW, WC_COMBOBOXA, WC_COMBOBOXW, и т.д.) некоторые из них имеют различия не только в кодировке
2. **Функций** ( SendMessageA, SendMessageW, SetWindowTextA, SetWindowTextW и т.п. )
3. В некоторых случаях - и **сообщений** (CBEM_GETITEMA, CBEM_GETITEMW, TCM_GETITEMA, TCM_GETITEMW, TCM_INSERTITEMA, TCM_INSERTITEMW  и т.п.)
4. И **уведомлений**( TVN_SELCHANGINGA, TVN_SELCHANGINGW, CBEN_GETDISPINFOA, CBEN_GETDISPINFOW и т.п. )
5. **Типов данных** - аналогично, с постфиксами **A** и **W**, соответственно

Но это следует делать только в исключительных случаях, когда действительно нужно жестко фиксировать кодировку.

Я бы рекомендовал пользоваться простыми макросами, чтобы избежать ненужных преобразований:

1. Повсеместно использовать тип **TCHAR** вместо char и wchar_t
2. Использовать макрос **TEXT( x )** вместо явных "Привет мир!" и L"Привет мир!"
3. А если в какой-то ситуации нет соответствующих макросов - сделать их, это не трудно:

   ```
   #ifndef UNICODE  
       #define tstring string  
   #else  
       #define tstring wstring  
   #endif  
   ...  
   std::tstring MyString = TEXT( "Привет мир!!!" );
   ```

Comment: фуф, а форматировать непросто, теперь я понимаю manking: у меня получилось обернуть последний код в <pre><code> только с помощью 2-х подряд идущих табуляторов в начале каждой строки, хотя в документации говорится об одном.

Answer (score 0):

Дело может быть в самих макросах. Определите их перед вызовом

```
 #include<windows.h>
```

Вот что сделайте:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
```

Answer (score -2):

LPCTSTR  это wchar_t * или char *

в vs 2010 это можно задать в настройках
свойства конфигурации  - общие - набор символов

Чтобы переводить строки туда обратно вот примерный код. 
Настройки в компиляторе должны стоять 
*Использовать набор символов юникода*

Пример: код функций ниже

```
std::system("chcp 1251");

LPCTSTR многобайтовая = L"text not russian.";
std::wcout << "\nстрока=" << многобайтовая;

// перевод в char*
std::string строка2 = LPWSTR_в_string((WCHAR*)многобайтовая);
std::cout << "\nстрока2=" << строка2;

//
LPCTSTR многобайтовая2 = (WCHAR*)string_LPWSTR(строка2);
std::wcout << "\nстрока многобайтовая=" << многобайтовая2;
```

Здесь код функций:

```
#ifndef _IOSTREAM_
#include <iostream>
#endif
#ifndef _NUMERIC_
#include <numeric>
#endif
#ifndef _STRING_
#include <string>
#endif
#include <windows.h>

static bool cvtLPW2stdstring(std::string & s, const LPWSTR pw, UINT codepage = CP_ACP)
{
    bool res = false;
    char *p = 0;
    int bsz;
    bsz = WideCharToMultiByte(codepage, 0, pw, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (bsz > 0) {
        p = new char[bsz];
        int rc = WideCharToMultiByte(codepage, 0, pw, -1, p, bsz, 0, 0);
        if (rc != 0) {
            p[bsz - 1] = 0;
            s = p;
            res = true;
        }
    }
    delete[]p;
    return res;
}

static std::string LPWSTR_в_string(LPWSTR строка)
{
    std::string строка_;
    cvtLPW2stdstring(строка_, строка);
    return строка_;
}

static LPWSTR string_LPWSTR(std::string строка, int кодировка = CP_ACP)
{
    LPWSTR res;
    DWORD res_len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, строка.data(), -1, NULL, 0);
    res = (LPWSTR) GlobalAlloc(GPTR, (res_len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, строка.data(), -1, res, res_len);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `Indentation` - для лохов.